# SQL Count data from 2 different tables

Tags: php, sql, database

I try to make a system of attendance of students to events. And I have three tables, one where you find official events, other where you find unofficial events and other with the students data.

When making a COUNT(*) at official events I have no problem, nor do I have a problem when making a COUNT(*) to unofficial events. My problem is when I make a COUNT(*) when trying to join the two tables.

TABLES:

stu

| ID | stureg | name | 2name | surname | 2surname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | Alvina | X | Reyes | Claudia |
| 2 | 506 | Jose | X | Albina | Perez |
| 3 | 585 | Wilt | X | Sharin | Colt |
| 4 | 413 | Hernando | X | Eulogio | Constantino |
| 5 | 713 | Zaida | X | India | Bautista |
| 6 | 426 | Eugenia | Melissa | Wilson | Reyes |

attendance

| ID | groupnum | IDevent | stureg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | 6 | 500 |
| 2 | 18 | 6 | 585 |
| 3 | 18 | 5 | 500 |
| 4 | 18 | 5 | 413 |
| 5 | 18 | 5 | 713 |
| 6 | 18 | 4 | 500 |
| 7 | 18 | 4 | 462 |
| 8 | 18 | 3 | 506 |
| 9 | 17 | 3 | 585 |
| 10 | 17 | 3 | 462 |
| 11 | 17 | 2 | 500 |
| 12 | 17 | 2 | 585 |
| 13 | 17 | 2 | 413 |
| 14 | 17 | 1 | 506 |
| 15 | 17 | 1 | 413 |
| 16 | 17 | 1 | 713 |

attendance_extra

| ID | groupnum | IDevent | stureg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 18 | 1 | 506 |
| 3 | 18 | 1 | 585 |

This is the query of official events

```
                SELECT
                    attendance.stureg, count(*) AS times
                    ,stu.name AS name
                    ,stu.2nameAS 2nameAS
                    ,stu.surname AS surname
                    ,stu.2surname AS 2surname
                    ,stu.stureg AS stureg
                FROM 
                    attendance
                    INNER JOIN stu ON attendance.stureg = stu.stureg
                WHERE 
                    attendance.groupnum = 18
                GROUP BY 
                    attendance.stureg
                HAVING COUNT(*)>0
                ORDER BY times DESC;
```

This is the query of un official events

```
                SELECT
                    attendance_extra.stureg, count(*) AS times
                    ,stu.name AS name
                    ,stu.2nameAS 2nameAS
                    ,stu.surname AS surname
                    ,stu.2surname AS 2surname
                    ,stu.stureg AS stureg
                FROM 
                    attendance_extra
                    INNER JOIN stu ON attendance_extra.stureg = stu.stureg
                WHERE 
                    attendance_extra.groupnum = 18
                GROUP BY 
                    attendance_extra.stureg
                HAVING COUNT(*)>0
                ORDER BY times DESC;
```

The Query that i try to use is that doesnt work for it was planned

```
                SELECT
                    attendance.stureg, count(*) AS times
                    ,stu.name AS name
                    ,stu.2nameAS 2nameAS
                    ,stu.surname AS surname
                    ,stu.2surname AS 2surname
                    ,stu.stureg AS stureg
                FROM 
                    attendance
                    INNER JOIN stu ON attendance.stureg = stu.stureg
                WHERE 
                    attendance.groupnum = 18
                GROUP BY 
                    attendance.stureg
                HAVING COUNT(*)>0
                    UNION (
                        SELECT
                            attendance_extra.stureg, count(*) AS times
                            ,stu.name AS name
                            ,stu.2nameAS 2nameAS
                            ,stu.surname AS surname
                            ,stu.2surname AS 2surname
                            ,stu.stureg AS stureg
                        FROM 
                            attendance_extra
                            INNER JOIN stu ON attendance_extra.stureg = stu.stureg
                        WHERE 
                            attendance_extra.groupnum = 18
                        GROUP BY 
                            attendance_extra.stureg
                        HAVING COUNT(*)>0
                        )
                ORDER BY times DESC;
```

The individual Querys work perfectly, it counts the duplicated stureg values, but when i use the last query it only merges the tables, but doesn't count the data, it just add rows at the end

First Query:

| ID | times | stureg | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 500 | Alvina X Reyes Claudia |
| 2 | 3 | 413 | Hernando X Eulogio Constantino |
| 3 | 3 | 585 | Wilt X Sharin Colt |
| 4 | 2 | 713 | Zaida X India Bautista |
| 5 | 2 | 462 | Eugenia Melissa Wilson Reyes |
| 6 | 2 | 506 | Jose X Albina Perez |

When im trying to merge the data:

| ID | times | stureg | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 500 | Alvina X Reyes Claudia |
| 2 | 3 | 413 | Hernando X Eulogio Constantino |
| 3 | 3 | 585 | Wilt X Sharin Colt |
| 4 | 2 | 713 | Zaida X India Bautista |
| 5 | 2 | 462 | Eugenia Melissa Wilson Reyes |
| 6 | 2 | 506 | Jose X Albina Perez |
| 7 | 1 | 500 | Alvina X Reyes Claudia |
| 8 | 1 | 506 | Jose X Albina Perez |
| 9 | 1 | 585 | Wilt X Sharin Colt |

So... what is the query you should apply for this to work as I have planned?

Comment: First, the UNION operator combines 2 samples, removes duplicates and returns the result. If you want to get count(*) from a combined table, it is better to use a nested query and (possibly) union all (so as not to exclude duplicates) 
Some like `select ID, stureg, name, sum(times) from (...your query) group by ID, stureg, name`

Comment: Can you please _properly_ explain your data model? So `attendance` is supposed to be the participants for the official events, and `attendance_extra` those for the unofficial ones? Why would these be two separate tables instead of one to begin with - when their structure appears to be identical? And why does your query that you say is for the unofficial events, still contain `FROM attendance` - should that not be `FROM attendance_extra` then?

Comment: @SwaD when I do this it says ```Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate column name 'stureg'```

And @CBroe , just a typo, sorry, and are two different tables, because at that time I did not think that I could add a boolean column asking if it was extra or not

Comment: @Andres Villarreal Try rename this `stu.stureg AS stureg` like `stu.stureg AS stureg2` In both requests

Comment: @SwaD '''Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'stureg' in on clause is ambiguous '''

Comment: show your result query with this error

Comment: ````#1052 - Column: 'stureg'  in on clause is ambiguous````

It says that when i run it directly on phpmyadmin